# Command to create database tables(with fields and relationship) based on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to specify the fields and relationships in the model and run a command to the rails create tables in the database based on the models, and then I can create or remove other fielda, change some relationships and run this command again and rails do update the tables in the database? I thought the migrate did it but after I read about it seems that it only creates the tables once and has no concept of model / db sync that i need.

Answer (score 0):

No you need to create a new migration anytime you need to update the database.  Changing some code in the model will not generate a migration.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you want a simpler way to write your migrations etc, I suggest you read more about the generators :)

For example :

```
rails generate model user first_name:string last_name:string birth_date:datetime friend:references
```

will directly generate the migration with the correct fields :)

And if you want to add a field after, you can write it like :

```
rails generate migration AddPseudoToUsers pseudo:string
```

And it will be correctly written normally :)

This is the doc
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-migration
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate